# How do I use UserDefaults to control a custom object

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nscoding

I am trying to make 2 classes, a Globals class and a Calibration class, to remember one Calibration object throughout the whole app run time. In other words, Calibration() would be initialized and Globals() would be initialized to call the Calibration object in any view controller. They would both be initialized in HomepageController's viewDidLoad(). 
This is my Globals class:

```
class Globals: NSObject, NSCoding {
var aCalValue: Double;
var bCalValue: Double;
var cCalValue: Double;

required init (aValue: Double, bValue: Double, cValue: Double) {
    aCalValue = aValue;
    bCalValue = bValue;
    cCalValue = cValue;

    super.init()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    aCalValue = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "aValue") as! Double
    bCalValue = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "bValue") as! Double
    cCalValue = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "cValue") as! Double
}

func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(aCalValue, forKey: "aValue")
    aCoder.encode(bCalValue, forKey: "bValue")
    aCoder.encode(cCalValue, forKey: "cValue")
}
}
```

And this is my Calibration class:

```
class Calibration {

var a: Double
var b: Double
var c: Double
var user: Globals

init() {
}

func setAValue(a: Double) {
    self.a = a;
}

func setBValue(b: Double) {
    self.b = b;
}

func setCValue(c: Double) {
    self.c = c;
}

func getAValue() -> Double {
    return self.a
}

func getBValue() -> Double {
    return self.b
}

func getCValue() -> Double {
    return self.c
}

func initializeUser() {
    user = Globals(aValue: getAValue(), bValue: getBValue(), cValue: getCValue())
}
}
```

How would I initialize both classes with the values the user entered the last time they opened the app?

Comment: The en-/decoding will not work. You have to use `decodeDouble(forKey:)` without type cast because in terms of `NSCoding` a `Double` is not an object. And remove all semicolons. They are needless in Swift.

Answer (score -1):

class User {

```
var token: String?

init(userDictionary: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
    token = userDictionary["token"] as? String
}

func toDictionary() -> Dictionary <String, Any> {
    var user : Dictionary <String, Any> = [:]
    user["token"] = token
    return user
}

func setAsCurrent() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(toDictionary(), forKey: "Cureent User")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}

static var current: User? {
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Cureent User") as? Dictionary<String, Any> {
        return User(user: data)
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

Comment: Good answers contain more than code. They **minimally** contain an explanation of (a) what the issue really is, and (b) how the code fixes the issue.